# refreshing page after router redirection

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, routes

In my  project (laravel+vuejs) i want to list the gantt chart of each project so when i click to the link of a specific project it redirect me to his gantt But in my case the the first click it work fine but one i click to choose other project it just change the url and dont refreshing the page (it didnt redirect me) it always work with the just first try.Any help guys?
this is the MainApp.vue:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-treeview" >         
            <li class="nav-item" v-for="projet in projects.projets" :key="projet.id" v-if="currentUser.role==='admin'">
        <router-link :to="`/gantt/${projet.id}`"  class="nav-link ">
          <i class="fas fa-circle" style="color:#05dfd7"> </i>
          <p>Gantt:{{ projet.name }}  </p>
        </router-link>
      </li>

       </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a **:key** attribute to your `<router-view>`

```
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
```

Your **${projet.id}** will be different each time, hence reload will be triggered.

---

**Edit**

**$route.fullPath** [Vue API](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties)

- type: string
- The full resolved URL including query and hash.

Comment: fullPath? like what in my case?

Comment: fullPath is in build in vuejs resource. Simply add `:key="$route.fullPath"` and your query will be resolved.

Comment: @piky try this `:to="'/gantt/' + projet.id"` Also is it projet or project?